# jQuery show/hide divs in sequence without overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a set of divs display one after the other in a timed sequence once a button is clicked, and at the same time take a picture with the webcam and send it to a server. I've got that working, however the function is triggering more than once when I double click the mouse, causing the divs to overlap eachother.

I'm using jQuery to show and hide the appropriate divs at certain times and I've tried using the .one handler but it doesn't appear to be working? I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if there is a better way this can be done?

Thanks!

```
var stages = [];
stages.push(document.getElementById('one'));
stages.push(document.getElementById('two'));
stages.push(document.getElementById('three'));
stages.push(document.getElementById('four'));

var currentStage = 0;

stages[currentStage].style.display = 'block';

function clickHandler() {
    setTimeout(showModal, 3000);
}


function showModal(){

     stages[currentStage].style.display = 'none';
         currentStage++;

         if (currentStage >= 3) currentStage = 0;

         stages[currentStage].style.display = 'block';

}

$("#analyse").one("click", function() {
     $("#one" ).fadeOut( "fast", function() {
           clickHandler();
           $( "#two" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {

               setTimeout(function(){$("#three").fadeIn()},6000);
               setTimeout(function(){$("#three").fadeOut()}, 7000);
               setTimeout(function(){$("#four").fadeIn()}, 7000);

          });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock the clicking after you first click it to prevent button spam. You can achieve this with a flag, and as soon as you enter `$("#analyse").one()`, place an `if (flag == true)` and immediately  turn the flag to `false`.

Once everything is done, 7 seconds later it seems, change it to `true`.

Edit

```
var canClick = true;

$("#analyse").one("click", function() {
    // Check if can start executing
    if (canClick) {
        // Stop next executions
        canClick = false;

        // After 8 seconds, allow executing again
        setTimeout(function () {
            canClick = true;
        }, 8000);

        $("#one" ).fadeOut( "fast", function() {
            clickHandler();
        $( "#two" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {

            setTimeout(function(){$("#three").fadeIn()},6000);
            setTimeout(function(){$("#three").fadeOut()}, 7000);
            setTimeout(function(){$("#four").fadeIn()}, 7000);
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Apologies, I'm quite new to javascript & jquery. Where would I place this flag in my code?

Comment: I've edited the response. Something like that should work, you can change my 8000 miliseconds to whatever you like.

Comment: Also added comments for understanding

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a flag you can also unbind:

$("#analyse").unbind('click');

But normally even a double click should call the function one only once. So I recommend trying before:

```
$("#analyse").unbind('click');
$("#analyse").one("click", function() {
     $("#one" ).fadeOut( "fast", function() {
           clickHandler();
           $( "#two" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {

               setTimeout(function(){$("#three").fadeIn()},6000);
               setTimeout(function(){$("#three").fadeOut()}, 7000);
               setTimeout(function(){$("#four").fadeIn()}, 7000);

          });
     });
});
```

I think its possible that you double binded a click event, so unbinding in front could fix it. If not just add it inside of the function.

```
    $("#analyse").one("click", function() {
         $("#analyse").unbind('click');
         $("#one" ).fadeOut( "fast", function() {
               clickHandler();
               $( "#two" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {

                   setTimeout(function(){$("#three").fadeIn()},6000);
                   setTimeout(function(){$("#three").fadeOut()}, 7000);
                   setTimeout(function(){$("#four").fadeIn()}, 7000);

              });
         });
    });
```

Comment: That seems to have stopped the divs from overlapping, however when double clicking it seems to show the divs one after the other quicker. Is there a way of just triggering it once so the fadeIn/fadeOut timer does the rest?

Comment: @Pete dont understand your question, its same fast/slow as before. If you want to change the speed, change the timer (ms) after the fadeIn calls. At the moment, #three will fade in after 6 seconds and fade out 1 second later. four will fade in also after 7 seconds.